# My webcam is not working in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I have just installed Ubuntu so I am new to Linux but I am facing a problem with my webcam (connected using USB cable) which was working perfectly fine in windows but not working properly in Ubuntu.

The video is freezing in cheese and flickering a lot in google meet.

Comment: What country are you in? Let us know and also guggle i915 and read up here https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kernel-5-9-10-1-video-not-usable-with-i915/39424

Comment: india... @darth_epoxy

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: India is 50Hz so that is good. It would be worth trying to change the frequency thus `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils` and then `v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl power_line_frequency=1` to make sure the camera is at 50Hz

Comment: @darth_epoxy ERROR: unknown control 'power_line_frequency'

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: i didnt understood what you are tying to say